# How different are US weigh stations for trucks than Canadian ones?

Tags: usa, canada, driving

I've never driven in the United States with a truck and it worries me a little bit. Do the weigh stations for trucks in the USA work the same way as they do in Canada? When I enter them with a truck, do they still have 2 lanes, one for the empty truck and the other one for the loaded trucks? Or we must all pass on the weigh scale?

Answer (score 6):

It varies from state to state.  Most probably have a bypass lane.

But there are some like the one on I-80 in NJ where bypass signal is on approach lane and it will direct you whether or not to enter a weigh station or re-enter the highway.

There are also bypass rules that exist for some states too which you can find online.  There are also applications like: [Drivewyze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drivewyze) that provide bypass information.